# Is the LinkIt 7688 Unofficially Unsupported?

Tags: linux

I'm working on a device powered by the LinkIt Smart 7688 at the moment, and having some driver issues with building a new OpenWRT image from scratch for it. One of those issues is that the WiFi driver blobs don't seem to have been updated for some time (~2017?), and won't work with the current kernel.

Has MediaTek stopped supporting the Linkit Smart 7688?

Comment: Can you contact them & ask them?

Comment: It took 4 phone calls in 4 continents to confirm that the answer is 'no, it's no longer supported'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mediatek provide it's own binary wifi driver in its feeds based on old 15.05 OpenWrt version. It seems not updated since years (https://github.com/MediaTek-Labs/linkit-smart-7688-feed). Hard to know it they still support it or not.

Luckily, some nice people build a new driver, more open called mt76 (https://github.com/openwrt/mt76). It's included in OpenWrt 18.06 (Kernel modules > Wireless Drivers) and it should work better then Mediatek one. Use last version (18.06.4) as it contains improvement of this driver.

Comment: How you install 18.06.4, i will try but read someone failed

Comment: Hello, you can flash it via an USB drive, according MediaTek documentation : https://docs.labs.mediatek.com/resource/linkit-smart-7688/en/tutorials/firmware-and-bootloader/update-the-firmware-with-a-usb-drive